# Jenkins plugin Manager: Updating plugin data fails

Tags: ssl, jenkins, dns, ssl-certificate, jenkins-plugins

When updating the plugin data (`http://<jenkins>/pluginManager/checkUpdatesServer`) I get this exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching 
updates.jenkins.io found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:214)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:96)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted
    (X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
Caused: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    (..)
```

Can somebody explain the issue? Is it an issue with our configuration or with the `updates.jenkins.io` site? Solutions / workarounds would be great.

Last successful update was 26 days ago.

We run Jenkins with the option

```
JAVA_ARGS="(..) -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false"
```

Jenkins is at 2.107.1, but prior 2.89.4 had the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up looking for the string "updates.jenkins.io" and got this match:

```
hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml:5: <url>https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json</url>
```

Reading about [this kind of error](https://github.com/dboissier/jenkins-control-plugin/issues/103) I suspected that this link might be outdated. Trying to locate a newer version I found [this hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml](https://github.com/Tarrasch/Jenkins-home-dir/blob/master/hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml) and it contained:

```
<url>http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json</url>
```

So I updated my version and was able to update my plugin data.

I tried to find the file in the Jenkins repository but did not find it, perhaps it is generated at runtime. However [this search](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=updates.jenkins-ci.org&type=) seems to confirm that this URL is a good choice.